# Red Folder Icon in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

May I know why is this folder in a red icon? I created some other folders and all were normal but not this one.

[image: Red Folder Icon]

Comment: Do you have an icon theme installed? Your icon theme will slightly change the folder icon if the folder has a special name (eg. `Test`, `Packages`, etc.)

Comment: Yes I do, the icon theme is called vscode-icon. And thank you so much for the reply :D no wonder the icon looks different than those I've created